# How to test a form Reset button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, reset

Googling around and not find a working solution...
Using Rails 3.2.11, RSpec 2.12.2 Capybara 2.0.2 I'm trying to test the "reset button" on a form (which works fine when testing with a browser)

I tried this code

```
scenario "Fill form then reset it" do
  visit contact_path
  fill_in 'message_name', :with => 'abc'
  fill_in 'message_email', :with => 'abc'
  fill_in 'message_subject', :with => 'abc'

  click_on 'Reset form'

  expect(page).to find_field('message_name').value.should == ''
end
```

The test fails with this error

```
 expected: ""
 got: "abc"
(compared using ==)
```

It seems the fields are not resetted at all.. (but in a browser they are)

What am I missing ? Something new in this version of Capybara or Rspec ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

My fault,

This type of feature/scenario requires js driver.

Selenium is included in the capybara gem but I forgot to activate it in my feature. To have it to work I just had to change the line

```
scenario "Fill form then reset it" do
```

to this one

```
scenario "Fill form then reset it", :js => true do
```

according the doc https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec. Now all works fine...

Hope it can help someone else ...
Cheers